# Problem with hackrom on real GBA cartridge

Tags: nintendo, rom, chip, game-cartridge, game-boy-advance

This is a problem that has brought me headaches, so I will try to explain as best as possible.

I have flashed with a Gbxcart several GBA ROMs in real cartridges (repro), working without any problem, but there is a special cartridge with which I have not had much luck, which is this one:

[image: Cartridge's chip]

In this cartridge the ROM doesn't start (it gives me white screen after the Nintendo boot screen). However, talking with the creator of the flasher, he managed to find the solution, which was to patch the ROMs with the program used for the Super Card, using this configuration:

[image]

According to what the flasher creator explained to me, the chip of this cartridge works at a much lower frequency than normal (as in the Super Card), so you have to patch the ROMs to work here.

The problem? There is one ROM that I have not been able to get to work on the cartridge with any configuration, which is Pokémon Fired Red (in English). For the same reason, the hackrom I want to record (which uses this game as a base) doesn't work either.

But here comes the most puzzling thing: the Spanish ROM (Pokémon Rojo Fuego), works without any problem on this cartridge with the patch applied!

What could be different about the English ROM that would prevent it from running? I just need to be able to flash this version.

I tried with several versions of the program (the latest, which is 2.71 and also some previous ones) but nothing has worked, and I insist, the problem only occurs with this particular ROM. Moreover, the patched ROM in English works perfectly in an emulator! So I really don't understand.

So my question is: Does the patched ROM of Pokémon Fire Red in English work on the Supercard, which has this same chip with a low frequency? (I don't have a Super Card Flashcard to test myself, only this repro cartridge with this "special" chip).

And if so, what settings did you use to patch the ROM?

Any suggestions or ideas? I've really tried everything and the issue is driving me crazy!

Comment: Yellow ring on the battery, Mock Nintendo copyright text on a PCB that's clearly not a Nintendo design, with sloppy soldering, and trying to flash FireRed onto something depicted sitting inside a red shell? I don't know what the front of the shell looks like, but that combination of details sounds more like you're making a counterfeit than a repro. (Proper repro PCBs don't try to misrepresent what they are.)